# Concatenate name of columns with data in rows using loop and export to text file

Tags: excel, vba, loops, concatenation

I try to create output text file using loop which create records consist of two rows ending with semicolon then continue with next record till last row which contains any data. First row of each output record will be still same, contains names of columns delimited by comma. Second row of each output record contains variable row values belongs to each column delimited by comma. from data table (sample attached). So if I have n columns and m rows, then result will looks as below:

```
Column_Name_1,Column_Name_2,Column_Name_3,Column_Name_4,Column_Name_n
Column_1_Data_Row_1,Column_2_Data_Row_1,Column_3_Data_Row_1,Column_4_Data_Row_1,Column_n_Data_Row_1;
Column_Name_1,Column_Name_2,Column_Name_3,Column_Name_4,Column_Name_n
Column_1_Data_Row_2,Column_2_Data_Row_2,Column_3_Data_Row_2,Column_4_Data_Row_2,Column_n_Data_Row_2;
Column_Name_1,Column_Name_2,Column_Name_3,Column_Name_4,Column_Name_n
Column_1_Data_Row_3,Column_2_Data_Row_3,Column_3_Data_Row_3,Column_4_Data_Row_3,Column_n_Data_Row_3;
Column_Name_1,Column_Name_2,Column_Name_3,Column_Name_4,Column_Name_n
Column_1_Data_Row_m,Column_2_Data_Row_m,Column_3_Data_Row_m,Column_4_Data_Row_m,Column_n_Data_Row_m;
```

[data_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPAKN.png)

I tried something, but stuck on cumulative outputs only. Export to text file works alright. I appreciate your help here. Thanks

```
Sub vba_concatenate()

Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim NumLastrow As Long
Dim NumLastcol As Long
Dim ChrLastcol As String
Dim SourceRange1 As Range
Dim SourceRange2 As Range
Dim ConcatenatedText1 As String
Dim ConcatenatedText2 As String
Dim b As String
Dim aa As String
Dim bb As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim cell

On Error Resume Next
 
NumLastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
aa = Cells(1, NumLastcol).Address
bb = Replace(aa, "$", "")
ChrLastcol = Replace(bb, "1", "")
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
b = "','"

Set SourceRange1 = Range("A1:" & ChrLastcol & "1")

    For Each cell In SourceRange1
    Cells(i, NumLastcol + 1).Value = ConcatenatedText1
    ConcatenatedText1 = ConcatenatedText1 & cell & b
    Next cell

For j = 2 To lastrow
    Set SourceRange2 = Range("A" & j & ":" & ChrLastcol & j)
    For Each cell In SourceRange2
    Cells(j, NumLastcol + 1).Value = ConcatenatedText1 & ConcatenatedText2
    ConcatenatedText2 = ConcatenatedText2 & cell & b
    Next cell
Next j

'part with export result
NumLastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
aa = Cells(1, NumLastcol).Address
bb = Replace(aa, "$", "")
ChrLastcol = Replace(bb, "1", "")

Set WorkRng = Application.Range(ChrLastcol & "1:" & ChrLastcol & lastrow)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\New_Export_" & Format$(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

EDIT: removed the semicolon from the header row

```vb
Sub vba_concatenate()
    Const LINE_SEP As String = vbCrLf
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range, hdr As String, r As Long, lnSep As String, s As String

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'for example
    
    hdr = RowToText(rng.Rows(1), ",")  'the header row
    
    For r = 2 To rng.Rows.Count
        s = s & lnSep & hdr & LINE_SEP & RowToText(rng.Rows(r), ",") & ";"
        If r = 2 Then lnSep = LINE_SEP 'add newlines for next rows...
    Next r
    'write to file
    PutContent "C:\temp\New_Export_" & Format$(Now, "yyyymmdd") & ".txt", s
 
End Sub

'Write `content` to a text file at path `f`
Sub PutContent(f As String, content As String)
    CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject"). _
                  opentextfile(f, 2, True).write content
End Sub

'Take a row `rw` and concatenate to a string using separator `sep`
Function RowToText(rw As Range, sep As String) As String
    'double `Transpose()` make a 1D array which can be passed to `Join()`
    RowToText = Join(Application.Transpose( _
             Application.Transpose(rw.Value)), sep)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Tim, nice and simple solution which works.